# DynamicZone: Field "micro_article_container" of type "[StrapiArticleMicro_article_container]" must have a selection of subfields

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

### The Problem

This error gets thrown when I run `gatsby build` on my project:

```
Field "micro_article_container" of type "[StrapiArticleMicro_article_container]" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "micro_article_container { ... }"?
```

### My setup

I am runing an **strapi (v3.6.8)** instance with the Graphql plugin together with an **gatsby** frontend.
There is the `article`type which has a dynamic zone (`micro_article_container`) filled with the component `micro_article`.

### When does the error occur?

To fetch data from my strapi Graphql API I run this query:

```
query MyQuery2($article: String) {
    strapiArticle(title: {eq: $article}) {
        id
        title
        published_at(formatString: "DD.MMMM.YYYY", fromNow: false)
        micro_article_container
    }
}
```

The query does work in the graphql playground provided. In development mode of gatsby the machine has no problem either.
Only when I try to build the gatsby project via `gatsby build` I get the error written above.

At first I thought I can modify the query so that micro_article_container has subfileds which are missing:

```
query MyQuery2($article: String) {
    strapiArticle(title: {eq: $article}) {
        id
        title
        published_at(formatString: "DD.MMMM.YYYY", fromNow: false)
        micro_article_container{
            title
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work either and throws the following error:

```
Field "micro_article_container" must not have a selection since type "JSON" has no subfields.
```

I can tell that I can not give subfields to micro_article_container because it is an array of objects and has the type JSON as displayed in the graphql playground. But why does it throw an error if I am not adding subfields :D

Since it is the first time I work with the dynamic zone of strapi I cant figure out what is wrong with my query. Furthmore I am confused about it working in dev mode but throwing an error if I want to build it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known bug as per:

- https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi/issues/256
- https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi/issues/257
- https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi/issues/252

Apparently, is fixed in this [pull-request](https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi/pull/258) so there's no "definitive" solution right now.

What you can do in the meantime is:

- Update to Gatsby 4 (at least `4.3.0-next.1`)
- Downgrading to Gatsby 3
- Install the fork while it's not being merged to the Strapi release:

  ```
  npm install marceligrabowski/gatsby-source-strapi#v4_prepublish
  ```